# Analytical badge (retired)

Tags: support, badges

Just out of curiosity:

Scrolling through the [list of badges](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges), at the end, I saw a badge with description

> Visited every section of the FAQ (**retired**)

What does retired mean here? Does that mean the badge is not given any longer?

Comment: See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185065/analytical-badge-can-this-be-marked-retired-or-something/185069#185069) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/188733#188733). (I was unaware of this. Luckily, [google knew](https://www.google.com/search?q=analytical+badge+retired+site%3Ameta.stackexchange.com) about that.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak, oh yes! Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the "retired" sobriquet means the Analytical badge can no longer be earned.

The original FAQ as a point of reference for new users was replaced long ago by the invitation to "[take a Tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour)" under the Help menu.  Hence the Analytical badge is more or less replaced by the Informed badge.

At this point the number of earned Informed badges exceeds the earned Analytical badges by an order of magnitude.